# Ruby mystery syntax error

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby so I'm afraid this is a dumb question, but I just cannot figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
init.rb: C:/Users/dmpk/Desktop/warranty-pro/lib/guide.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Here is a sample of the file in question

```
require 'claim'

class Guide

  class Config
    @@actions = ['add', 'list', 'find', 'quit']

    def self.actions
      @@actions
    end
  end
```

The first line in the example above is line 1, the last line is line 10.
So it says it was expecting 'end' on line 2, and I don't understand why.

Comment: You're missing an `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody comes across this question later, I fixed the issue. All I did was copy all the code in the file, delete the file, then make a new file with the same name and paste all the code in. After that it worked. So...I don't really know what the actual problem was, but it's fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

Fix the formatting and the answer becomes clear

```
require 'claim'

class Guide
   class Config
      @@actions = ['add', 'list', 'find', 'quit']

      def self.actions
        @@actions
      end
   end
```

Every `class` and `def` needs to have a matching `end`. You are missing one.

Comment: Well this is just a short snippet from the begging of the code I have, looking through everything in Sublime, I can see the end for the Guide class, but it's like 80 lines down. I didn't think I should post that much text in the question. Should I post everything? Also, if it were the Guide class missing an end, wouldn't that show an error down further at the bottom of the code, as opposed to right near the beginning?

Comment: Yes, normally I would expect the line number to be the last line in that case. If your code is really long you can upload somewhere like https://gist.github.com/ or http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Like this? https://gist.github.com/Cymricz/c406d01571524eecb61cb43274d0f7b6

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with that code. My only guess is that the error message is coming from the `claim` you are requiring, but I would expect that error message to point to that file.

Comment: Oh good, I'm not the only one confused. I will post a link to the claim file when I get home from work then. I would assume the same thing, but I thought maybe the error is indicating the line after the actual mistake?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Cymricz/322dab1399f7658f00b15ecf6a5171d6 here is a link to the 'claim' file that is being required. Do you think it matters that this code is super incomplete? I just wanted to run it to see if everything works that I have so far.

Comment: Well crap. I guess it really is a mystery. Okie dokey! I'll look into it, I must have done something wriong.

Comment: Well crap. I guess it really is a mystery. Okie dokey! I'll look into it, I must have done something wrong. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I formatted your code and it seems you missed the `end` for the `Guide` class.